# How to get ILSpy to show compiler generated code

Tags: c#, compilation, syntactic-sugar, ilspy

I've written and built this app:

```
namespace Test
{
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myClass = new MyClass();
            foreach (var item in myClass.CountFrom(1, 4))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);                
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public IEnumerable<int> CountFrom(int start, int limit)
        {
            for (int i = start; i <= limit; i++)
            {
                yield return i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I view the code in ILSpy, based on the .exe in the bin/Debug folder, it doesn't show the state machine code I was hoping to see:
[image]

How can I get it to show the [compiler generated code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGALAbgFgAoFAJmxJIDsIw4oAHCAYzgwBUGYSBvEjIIwCh5LNgDsIwf2JD54gGxZcGALIQAltQAUONAG0AuhggIA5lACU0hbIUOMANzMYwATwDCAG2hQMALwY1HAA7upevlBQOlZEco7yAGYA9ghwrAAWGDouCBia8GAF1G6RfgB0nikArtQwAGIIKWA62AA0GLhWNgmJMrb9otgAnDqFcGBxQw6DjgC+cw7V1FAp3nAVAEoZACax8YmLfRjHtigAzFhkET5+tvaOl+IXADzaMAB8GNV1jc2tD4YWBmGCdIHeTRgQq9RKPIapfLjeoFQLAmCg/Co15BSHQmBYzQAaiJsJm8Jmghw2CwEgKhxmxyOtmO8yAA)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to "View->Option" and under the "Decompiler" tab, you can uncheck "C#2.0->Decompile enumerator(yield return)" :
[image]